# Como centralizar o menu CSS

Tags: css, html5, app, apk

Pessoal estou com esse projeto aqui para a partir dele criar a estrutura de um aplicativo, porem não consigo de forma alguma centralizar os menus.

Também gostaria que a página ficasse responsiva.

**Segue o código:**

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.menu{list-style:none; border:1px solid #c0c0c0; float:left; }

.menu li{position:relative; float:left; border-right:0px solid #c0c0c0; }

.menu li a{color:#333; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 10px; display:block;}

.menu li a:hover{background:#333; color:#fff; -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC; -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc; text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff; }

.menu li   ul{position:absolute; top:25px; left:0; background-color:#fff; display:none; }

.menu li:hover ul, .menu li.over ul{display:block;}

.menu li ul li{border:1px solid #c0c0c0; display:block; width:150px;}



.menu{
padding:5px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
margin: 1% 1% 2% 1%;
max-width: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menu em CSS Dropdown Horizontal - Linha de C�digo</title>


<!-- Aqui chamamos o nosso arquivo css externo -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">

<!--[if lte IE 8]> <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->
</head>


<body>

<nav> </nav>
<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem alguns problemas e outros itens que podem ser melhorados:

**1.** `<nav> </nav>`

Todo o menu deveria estar entre essas tags:

```
<nav>
   MENU AQUI
</nav>
```

**2.** Repetições de `<ul>` desnecessárias

Você não precisa fazer repetidos `<ul>` para criar cada botão do menu. Além de ser uma prática ruim, polui e torna seu código mais pesado. Crie apenas uma lista `<ul>` e cada `<li>` sendo um botão:

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

**3.** Para centralizar o menu, você pode usar `display: flex;` com `justify-content: center;`.

Veja seu código melhorado abaixo e auto ajustável à largura da tela:

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
   font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
}

.menu{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
   margin: 2% 1%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   list-style:none;
}

.menu li{
   border-radius: 10px;
   width:150px;
   border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   position:relative;
   margin: 0 1%;
}

.menu li a{
   border-radius: 10px;
   color:#333;
   text-decoration:none;
   padding:5px 10px;
   display:block;
   padding: 10px;
}

.menu li a:hover{
   background:#333;
   color:#fff;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
   text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
}

nav{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul class="menu">
   
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
   
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Quando eu executo aqui no site fica responsivo, mas quando faço isso fora daqui não fica.